# Why sometimes a process, that locks a folder, is still open, after closing all content of the folder in used programs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, eclipse

I tried to rename a folder and got a message, that it is opened in another program and I have to close it to do this.
As I used the recource-monitor to find, what prevents renaming the folder, I found an eclipse-process.
Recently I modifyed some files inside that folder with this coding-program.
But I closed all tabs in the program, that had theese files open.

Why this program still blocked the folder and i had to close it whoole?

How to stop a program from blocking folders without closing it whoole?

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes programs keep temporary files open in the background in order to e.g reopen them quickly.

I work with Autocad a lot and sometimes I have to close the entire program before being able to move or delete certain files because for some reason it keeps it open in the background.

If closing the program doesn't solve your problem, try restarting your computer.